# Deactivation of SharePoint Online account

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-accounts

I have a **SharePoint Online account** that has been as site collection admin to all of the site collections in tenant. Now that employee is leaving the organization. So we have to deactivate that account.
But We have uploaded many files,published most of the designer workflows using that account only.

How can I assign all this content another office 365 account?

I have multiple(15-20) site collections and several(5-10) workflows in each site collection.

So Help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Could you please accept one of the answers, if they helped you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not matter if you deactivate the account, because the uploaded documents can be opened and published workflows can still work. 
It will be a good idea to check in all checked-out documents prior to the user leaving the company. This can be done via PowerShell as well.

The workflow can be republished by another account and the documents can be assigned to a different user. As there probably are a lot of documents and changing them manually will be tiresome and time consuming, using PowerShell for SPO can help you automate this job.

But in my opinion, replacing the user just because he/she uploaded the documents, it is a bit of waste of time. You have to make sure that those documents are assigned to a different account as ownership. There must be someone else who has access to those documents as well. Still the site owner can take ownership of these documents.

Comment: So How about publishing multiple workflows using Power Shell ? because I am very unsure about number of workflows. It might be 100 or more within different 15-20 site collections.

Comment: Yes, that can be done as well. There are plenty of Powershell scripts to publish a workflow. eg.: https://piasys.com/blog/how-to-publish-a-workflow-definition-in-sharepoint-using-powershell/

Comment: Are they sharepoint designer workflows or MS Flow?

Comment: Only Designer workflows 2010 and 2013 both.

Comment: OK, then you use powershell to publish them, even you can attach them to new lists and libraries using powershell.

Comment: Will it work if I change the email id rather than deactivating that user id ? for ex. spuser@tenant.com =>spadmin@tenant.com.

Comment: yeah, I am using SharePoint Online and SharePoint Designer 2010 and 2013 workflows.

Comment: Yes, you can change that of course. It is best you dis-activate the account of the user afterwords because he will still have access to your tenant, after leaving the company. 

one more thing. You cannot use workflow 2010, 2013 directly on SharePoint online. You are talking now about On-prems or Online?

Comment: I am talking about SharePoint Online and I have created several designer workflows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83573/discussion-between-burre-ifort-and-gopal-zadafiya).

Answer (score 0):

For the files that uploaded by the deleted user, we can assign full control permission to the new user accounts.

For workflow that published by the deleted user, we can still use the workflow even though the user is deleted. We can navigate the SharePoint Designer, access the workflow and republish them with the new user accounts who have full control in the site collection.

More information, you can check [Delete a user from your organization](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/delete-a-user-from-your-organization-d5155593-3bac-4d8d-9d8b-f4513a81479e)

Comment: Thanks @Hellofiona_MSFT, But I don't know how many workflows I have. We have many site collections. each site collection might have 5-6 workflows.